# Module of distributed Framework not found in InterfaceBuilder

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, frameworks, storyboard

before Xcode 7, I were able to build a Framework for (development) distribution for both device and simulator (usually as a fat-binary) and include it into any of my projects. When I now try to build and integrate the Framework I still can see my classes and the Framework-Module and use both in my code, but when I try to reference them from within my Storyboard, they are no longer visible.

Correct me if I am wrong - I've been working with Frameworks since swift was released, but my memories might deceive me here - but I remember being able to use classes from a Framework and reference them in an InterfaceBuilder-file in the previous versions. Referencing a framework-class is no problem when the Framework-target is build from within the same Project.

To test this, I simply set up a Framework-Project and added a custom UIViewController. Then I've build the Framework and imported it into another SingleView-Application. I already checked if there is a possible setting preventing the Framework-module from being visible (BitCode, SDK, Deployment Target) and configured the ViewController as public.

Maybe I'm just missing some new setting Apple introduced in Xcode 7 ;-)

Comment: Do you have any code snippets?

Comment: Nothing worth posting. As I said, the framework and the project I'm importing it in are the defaults created by Xcode. Didn't add anything to it.